# Upload photos to google assistant

Tags: google-assist-api

I'm not so sure this is the right place to ask it; So, if not, please tell me where should I migrate it to.

I'm trying to upload photos to google assistant. Is there a way to do it? (even in an indirect way)

Thank you in advance